# Match and separate Rails serialized array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, serialization

I have a `Company` model as follows:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employee_roles
  has_many :employees
  validates :company_name, uniqueness: true
  serialize :contractors, Array

end
```

Now I have a page where an admin can add/remove `contractors` to/from  a company. To add a `contractor` I just store the contractor id in `contractors` as follows:

```
def assign_contractors
  @company = Company.find(company_contractor_params[:company_id])
  @company.contractors << company_contractor_params[:contractor_id]
  @company.save
end
```

I want to show two separate lists on a single page now. Such that one list is of all the `contractors` associated  with a `company` while the other is of all the `contractors` who are not associated with that company.

```
def contractor_list
  @contractors = Contractor.where({ verified: true,
                        validated: true })
              .where('membership_type != ?', Contractor.membership_types["no_membership"])
  @company = Company.find(contractor_company_params[:company_id])

  @selected_contractors = @contractors.select { |c| @company.contractors.include? c.id }
  return render :status => 200, :json => {
    :contractors => @contractors,
    :selected_contractors => @selected_contractors
  }
end
```

But it's giving me an empty list even though my `contractors` for the selected company has the values `["2", "1"]` which I checked by doing `Company.find(1).contractors` through the `rails console`

How can I get a list of selected contractors from `serialized` data?

Comment: I think the key is `["2", "1"]`, check at the quotes, they are strings, `@company.contractors.include? c.id` will never be true because `c.id` is integer. Try with `c.id.to_s`.

Comment: @fanta I tried that too but no luck, it still gives me an empty list

Comment: have you checked `@contractors` to see which contractors it contains ?, perhaps it has different ones/

Answer (score 0):

@fanta is right the problem was the `to_s` since it was being saved as a string. I still wasn't convinced with the query I wrote though and I ended up using the following query instead:

```
@selected_contractors = Contractor.find(@company.contractors)
```

which would reduce the queries from n to 1 as suggested over [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/165878/extract-list-of-selected-contractors-by-matching-serialized-array-in-rails)